# trouble with python objects

Tags: python, class, object

```
class dog(object):
    def __init__(self, name = "", breed = "", age = "", weight = "", colour = ""):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.colour = colour
    def printDog(self):
        print("Name: " + self.name)
        print("Breed: " + self.breed)
        print("Age: " + self.age)
        print("Weight: " + self.weight)
        print("Colour: " + self.colour)


def main():
    chester = dog()
    lola = dog()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

So in the `dog` class. I make you able to make your own instance of a dog and give it attributes, and I also have a function that allows you to print the info about your dog instance.

But when I make a `dog` in `main`, I can't call it in the shell. It's weird help me.

Comment: What do you mean, "call it in the shell"?

Comment: Why would the names persist after the function has returned?

Comment: What do you mean you "can't call it in the shell"?  You need show the code that you're using to "call it in the shell".  Your `chester` and `lola` are local variables inside the function `main`, so they won't be visible outside that function.

Comment: thank you so much brenbarn. I'm stupid

Comment: @lopesam As an aside, you can change that `printDog` function into a definition for the `__str__` magic method. `def __str__(self): return "Name:   {0.name}\nBreed:  {0.breed}\nAge:    {0.age}\nWeight: {0.weight}\nColour: {0.color}".format(self)` then you can `print` a dog object to get all that, rather than calling its print method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to instantiate the dogs like following

```
chester = dog(name = "chester", breed = "pomerian", age = "2 years", weight = "70 kgs", colour = "white")
```

and then view them like

```
chester.printDog()
```

You are instantiating the dogs inside the `main` function, so they won't be available to you outside that function.

Also, as it currently stands, all your inputs have to be strings, or you will get `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` if you give integer values for age or weight attributes.